# Spoofing OS during browsing

Tags: operating-systems, os-fingerprinting, fingerprinting, reconnaissance

I am using http://www.mybrowserinfo.com/ to gather some info about me while browsing. 
I want to change my OS to appear that its a Windows Xp machine.(No VM solutions please:D)

If you have any related material how this sites fingerprint you please add it also.(same way as Nmap ? specifics in TCP/IP stack ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it is looking at the user agent in your http request. Try setting the user agent in your HTTP request to Windows NT 5.1

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx

If you don't want to do this manually, there are a number of tools out there that will let you specify this point/click style.

Here is a good article that talks about how to start Chrome with a different default user agent:
http://www.parmiter.com/applications/2012/02/RP773

Answer (score 2):

There are also options such as: 
`User Agent Switcher`

**Firefox Add-on:**
https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

**Chrome Extension:**
(Also available, query for it, OP asked about Firefox, so priority)

This does **NOT** however change your native screen resolution, which is also typically passed.

So, for instance, if you are trying to tell a site that you "are" a Windows phone you can, but know that Google adwords, analytics, and anyone else who cares, leverage screen size resolution to aid in fingerprinting/marketing so it is nothing new.

Macbook Pro screens only come in a few sizes.

**Check out what you are passing here:**

http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/

Comment: agent switcher works great for Rakuten, thanks.